# Combobox's list not in proper position

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, flex4.5, datagridcomboboxcolumn, itemeditor

I am using spark's combobox as Itemeditor in advance datagrid.
It is working properly but fails to open properly when the Combobox is opened near the bottom of the Flex Object.

It tends to open upwards for the first time (which is perfectly fine) but when I type alphabets to search, it filteres the records and adjust the height of the list properly but could not make to manage the Y cordinate so as to keep the list adjacent to its textbox.

Attaching the two snap shot. Please suggest any solution to fix this.
Thanks

[image][image]

Comment: Which version of Flex are you using?  Sounds like you should submit a bug to the Apache Flex project.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply.
I am using flex 4.5

Comment: If you give us your code fragment we could try to execute it. So you could get to know if it is a general problem or yours.